# Linux Perform MySQL Backup to time-based path from Webmin

Tags: mysql, backup, ubuntu-server, cron-task, webmin

I was trying to setup a scheduled task in Linux Ubuntu Server 12.04 (CronJob) to perform a daily backup of all my MySQL Databases on midnight.

I have installed the known [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) (A nice web interface for managing the Web Servers).

So my issue is: whenever the backup is being performed, the files are getting overwritten!

That means: The backup of the day before yesterday are LOST, only the "Yesterday" backup is being saved!

I have tried something like setting dynamic file path like:

**/var/www/mysqlbackups/%d-%m-%y**

but I had no success with that :(

Can anybody help me.

Thanks alot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a shell script (not for webmin). Put it in /etc/cron.daily.

The scripts makes a backup of the database (stores it as .gz), then uploads it by ssh to another server. For the auth. i setup ssh keys, so no password is needed.
The backup files have a unique name, so you don't overwrite the backup files.

This is how you can create a filename within script:

```
now=`date  +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
dst_path=/var/local/backups
filename="$dst_path/$database.$now.sql.gz"
```

Then you should write a a small script that removes all backup files that are older then x days.

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# Creates a backup of a MySQL databases and uses ssh (sFTP) to send if  to another server
# This script shouldbe called from the crontab

PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

# MySQL user and password
mysql_cmd=/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqldump
mysql_usr=user_name
mysql_pass=password

# destination ssh
dst_user=user_name
dst_hostname=192.168.1.1

# Database to backup
database=test

# create timestamp
now=`date  +%Y%m%d_%H%M`

# where we store the files
dst_path=/var/local/backups

# backup filename
filename="$dst_path/$database.$now.sql.gz"
dst_filename="$database.$now.sql.gz"

# run backup
$mysql_cmd -u $mysql_usr --password=$mysql_pass  $database | gzip > $filename

# upload to sever (ssh)
scp $filename $dst_user@$dst_hostname:
```

Answer (score 16):

> MySQL Database Server > Module Config > Chose Yes on "Do strftime substitution of backup destinations?"

It work for me! :)

Comment: And here is a list of variables if you turn on "variable substitution" -- http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/id,template_variable_listing

Answer (score 11):

You can use dynamic path, but before you must enable it in module config:

```
System > Filesystem Backup > Module Config > Do strftime substitution of backup destinations? > Yes
```

(If you are not sure about placeholders, just click on the text "Do strftime substitution of backup destinations?" in the config and help will show you.)

Comment: This is only for filesystem backups (vritualmin 4.08). The answer of @Mr Vector is the correct one.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and solved like this :

From **Server** select **MySQL Database Server**.
Go to **Module config** (top left), and select **Do strftime substitution of backup destinations?** to **Yes**.

I use db_%d-%m-%Y.sql format for backups. (db_13-03-2013.sql)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in following way

Webmin > MySQL Database Server > select database > backup Database > file path 
in Other backup option you can use > Command to run after backup 
Enter ======> mv file path/filename file path/filename_`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`.sql